# Jquery library not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I'm using XSLT as my view layer and i want to include Jquery in my page so i did the following but with no mean the library still not working:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">&#160;</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("_______");
   $(document).ready() {
      alert("Jquery is working");
   });
</script>
```

Note: the `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` file is in the same folder where my XSL file exist, 
the strange thing i note is that the `alert` at the first line in the script is not working which means that the javascript at all is not working!! i tried that at chrome,firefox and IE with the same result.

Comment: Did you know, jQuery is now at version 1.10??

Answer (score 5):

try it like this

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     alert("Jquery is working");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

     alert("_______");
     $(document).ready(function () {
         alert("Jquery is working");
     });

</script>
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/Jv76G/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  //&#160; remove this content
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("_______");
   $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("Jquery is working");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://raygun.com/blog/jquery-is-undefined/. I added this code `<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/your/jquery_file.js"><\/script>')</script>` below before the `</body>` tag and succeeded in removing the "jQuery is not loaded / found" warning